# Suspend (ban) account of spamming user account

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation

A user calling themselves *hitasoftmadurai* has been banned several times now, for spamming with nonsensical answers, usually by cobbling together fragments found on the page.

Please suspend this account so they can no longer post.

---

Add new incarnations below:

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/28741/hitasoftmadurai (removed)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/28895/hitasoftmadurai (removed)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/29116/hitasoftmadurai (removed)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/30444/hitasoft-madurai (removed)

Comment: I'm so tempted to add this http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk to the list...

Answer (score 3):

The situation has been taken care of.

Comment: Thank you. I know mods don't talk much about these situations, but can you indicate if our guess that it was a runaway (not necessary malicious) bot?

Comment: It wasn't an SE system bot, and beyond that we don't really know anything more than you all about it. The content certainly seemed to suggest a bot.

Comment: Shouldn't runaway sentient bots be on-topic for SFF.se?

Comment: @DVK Only if they give an answer relevant to the question.

Comment: @DVK - Only if they can time-travel

Comment: @Kevin Relevant: http://xkcd.com/810/